# MySQL - Select only those that have not another value

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I'd need a query to SELECT all of these entries that are not repeated with another value. I explain the case in the next lines.

#### The situation

I've got a table of items and values. Each item can be repeated with different values. Let's say I have the following set of records in Table B:

```
 item_id    value    type_value

ID Item A     0          0
ID Item B     0          0
ID Item A     1          0
ID Item C     1          1
```

These items, as probably you have already guessed, are IDs, so the "original" items with their information are in another table. What I'm trying to do is to select from the "original" table those items which are in this second table that I've explained.

#### What I need

As I introduced before, I need to select from a Table A all those items which IDs are IN Table B, but only those which have the value set to 0 and no other record is set to 1 with the same type of "type_value".

Because of the "original" table, I need to do so in a WHERE clause with an INNER SELECT. The result that would be output would be, in this case:

```
 item_id    value    type_value

ID Item B     0          0
ID Item C     1          1
```

If we decided to only SELECT those with a specified type_value, I know how to do that, so do not worry about it.

#### The problem

I am able to do so, at least almost. My problem comes when I have the same item_id with different value fields, so when I try to say "WHERE value != 1", for example, this still gets selected as there is another record with value = 0.

#### The question

How could I SELECT the rows I'd like in an inner select in a WHERE clause of a main query **without having to repeat the whole SELECT with a NOT IN and adding a "WHERE value = 1" to exclude those who have that value?**

As it can be a long and complex query (the main one), I'd like to keep it as simple as possible. Of course, as I said before, I can copy the whole query and select those with value set to the one I do not want to, and put a "AND NOT IN" before that SELECT. But that'd repeated code and I think performance could be affected.

Thanks to all of you for your time!

**If you need further explanation, please, let me know!**

#### EDIT

**Table_A**

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | Item A |
+----+--------+
| 2  | Item B |
+----+--------+
| 3  | Item C |
+----+--------+
```

**Table_B**

```
+---------+-------+
| item_id | value |
+---------+-------+
| 1       | 0     |
+---------+-------+
| 2       | 0     |
+---------+-------+
| 1       | 1     |
+---------+-------+
| 3       | 1     |
+---------+-------+
```

**Sample query**

```
SELECT name 
FROM Table_A
WHERE id IN (SELECT item_id 
      FROM Table_B
      WHERE "item_value is equal to 0 and no other row has this item_id with a item_value different from 0")
```

**Result query**

```
+---------+
|   name  |
+---------+
|  Item B |
+---------+
```

Comment: You have put a lot of effort into your question, so I feel awful saying this: but I don't understand it. Can you please provide sample data for TableA, and TableB and the "expected result". Even better would be to set-up a http://SQLfiddle.com.

Comment: Done! Added the sample query of what it should look alike! Thanks for your time!

Comment: so Item B is the "expected result"? I think Steve has your answer (below) using HAVING SUM(b.value) = 0 [or MAX(b.value) = 0 would also work]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, for example:

```
SELECT a.*, b.itemid, SUM(b.value) AS vc FROM tableb b
INNER JOIN tablea a ON a.itemid = b.itemid
GROUP BY b.item_id
HAVING vc = 0
```

Comment: I'll give it a try! However, this only works if the values are just 0 and 1. For me, it's a valid approach, but if the item_values could have more than just 0 and 1, could you explain - if you don't mind - how you would do it? Thanks for your time and I'll try that as soon as I can!

Comment: From your OP you said `"but only those which have the value set to 0"` which is why a SUM() = 0 will be valid despite what other numbers are present.  If you wanted to expand this requirement to any other number then this solution woudln't work - actually it would be very complex to get something to work and still retain good performance. A full schema and / or SQLFiddle would be needed to answer that properly.

Comment: Got it! You're right. As I said, as for now, the value equal to 0 is more than valid for me! So, I will try that and give a feedback! Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Adracat You might consider providing a more representative data set (and desired result set). In fact, if you had just done that to begin with, you may have saved yourself a LOT of typing!

Comment: It works like a charm! Another problem has come to me now, but it's a little bit different from this question so I'll try to solve it for my own! Thanks to all of you for your time and your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I used really simple query structure to make you understand the solution.
There might be better queries to do the job.

Here goes:

First you need to get the rows that you do not want to appear:

This is how it is done :

```
SELECT item_id,COUNT(item_id) how_many FROM my_table GROUP BY item_id HAVING (how_many>1)
```

Now you need to select from the table the rows that item_id does not appear in the above query, it is done this way:

```
SELECT T1.item_id,T1.value,T1.type_value
FROM my_table T1 
WHERE (T1.item_id not in (SELECT T.item_id from (SELECT item_id,COUNT(item_id) how_many FROM my_table GROUP BY item_id HAVING (how_many>1))T ))
```

You can see that I used the "not in" operator and that I named the previous result table - T

Make sure you understand the above
Ask if you need more info